# Attach PHP fputcsv as PHPMailer attachment

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

The first part of my function generates a CSV file using PHP's `fputcsv`, I want to then email that CSV using PHPMailer which I also have installed.

**Generate CSV file from array.**

```
$output = fopen("php://output",'w') or die("Can't open php://output");

// Add column headings.
fputcsv($output, array('SKU', 'ASIN', 'Current Rating', 'Previous Week', 'Difference', 'Category', 'Total Ratings'));

foreach( $ratings as $rating ) {
    fputcsv( $output, $rating );
}

fclose($output) or die("Can't close php://output");
```

**Send email via PHPMailer**

```
// Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new \PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();

// Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();

// Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.eu.mailgun.org';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = '';
$mail->Password = '';

// Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('', '');
$mail->Subject = 'Weekly ASIN Ratings Report';

$mail->Body = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';

// Attach an image file
$mail->addAttachment('');

// Send the message, send errors to Sentry.
if (!$mail->send()) {
    \Sentry\captureMessage( $mail->ErrorInfo );
} else {
    echo 'Message sent!';
}
```

**What I tried**

```
$mail->addAttachment($output);
```

I got the email but no attachment at all.

Comment: http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_addStringAttachment

Comment: @cOle2 - `$mail->addStringAttachment($output, 'report.csv');` - "Warning: base64_encode() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given"

Comment: php://output sends to browser. You probably want php://memory instead.

Comment: Either write the CSV data to a local file and pass its path to `addAttachment()`, or grab the output in a string and pass it to `addStringAttachment()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like -

```
$mail->AddAttachment( $filePath , 'filename.csv' );
```